# C# - How to pause the program until an image file is done being overwritten

Tags: c#, image, save, ocr, thread-sleep

In my program, there is a process where it goes like this:

> Save Image (Overwrite the existing one) -> Run OCR on this image -> Return string result

This process can be repeated several times in a row, and without `Thread.Sleep()`, it results in:

> **1st iteration:** Save img01 -> Run OCR on img01 -> return result of img01
>
> **2nd iteration:** Save img02 to replace img01 -> *still* run OCR on img01 (old img) -> return result of img01 (old result)

*(img01 and img02 share a same file name/path)*

---

Because there is no pause in the flow, I notice the OCR will take place on `img01` instead of `img02` because `img02` is still being saved.

The unreliable way for my current PC to work is simply put down a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` between saving image and running OCR.
However I can imagine this is not the right solution since different computer will take different times to save an image right?

How can I make the program to pause dynamically and wait for an image to be completely overwritten before it continues to the next step?

Comment: Coulndt you show off the code for this process?

Comment: You're right to think that Thread.Sleep(1000) is not a proper solution.  What may work on one system may not work on another depending on a number of factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be this:

First you should check if `img02` exists and if the file is curently in use.

In order to check if `img02` exists you could do something like: `File.Exists(path)`

Then check if the file is in use, something like:

```
protected virtual bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
{
    FileStream stream = null;

    try
    {
        stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        //the file is unavailable because it is:
        //still being written to
        //or being processed by another thread
        //or does not exist (has already been processed)
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close();
    }

    //file is not locked
    return false;
}
```

If the file is not in use then you can proceed to the next step.

Comment: I would use this in combination with a small sleep time or the system may slow to a crawl.

Comment: So is it appropriate to do `while (isFileLocked(img)) {Thread.Sleep(1000)};` So I stay in the loop until the file is finally unlocked?

Comment: @Liren yes. Try it and see if the result is what you expect.

Comment: @Liren I would rather go for a `for(int i=0; i< 500; i++) { if(isLocked) Thread.Sleep(100); }` loop for beaing able to handle an app-hang.

Comment: @C4ud3x Yep, that's better. Thank you! So it's actually okay to use `Thread.Sleep()` right? I remember reading somewhere saying `Thread.Sleep()` is a bad idea.